# powershell equivalent of javascript array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX) for string[]

Tags: powershell

javascript
array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)

**index**   Required.  The position to add/remove items. Negative value defines the position from the end of the array.

**howmany** Optional. Number of items to be removed.

**item1**, ..., **itemX**   Optional. New elements(s) to be added.

Now, I want to get this same functionality in Powershell:

```
function splice {
    param(
        [string[]]$Array,
        [int32]$Index,
        [int32]$HowMany,
        [string[]]$Item
    )

}

$lines = @(
    "abc",
    "xyz"
    "123"
)


$lines = splice -Array $lines -Index 1  -HowMany 0 -Item "foo", "bar"
```

Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking more of using an [ArrayList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist), because that already has methods `RemoveRange()` and `InsertRange()`:

```
function splice {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$Array,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [int32]$Index,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
        [int32]$HowMany = 0,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 3)]
        [string[]]$Item = $null
    )
    # convert negative index to positive
    $idx = if ($Index -lt 0) { $Array.Count + $Index } else { $Index }
    if ($idx -lt 0 -or $idx -ge $Array.Count) {
        Write-Error "Index $Index out of range"
        return
    }
    # initialize an ArrayList with all values from $Array
    # an ArrayList can hold elements of any type
    $aList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new($Array)
    # In this case, since you are using [string[]] to typecast the parameters for $Array and $Item, you could also use
    # $aList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new($Array)

    # do we need to remove items?
    if ($HowMany -ge 0) {
        $aList.RemoveRange($idx, [math]::Min($HowMany, $aList.Count - $idx))
    }
    # do we need to insert/append new items?
    if ($Item.Count) {
        $aList.InsertRange($idx, $Item)
    }
    # return as array. use unary comma to ensure the function returns an array
    # even if there is only one element left
    ,$alist.ToArray()
}
```

Some tests:

```
$test = 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', '123'

splice $test -1 5 'add this','and this one too'  # remove last item '123' and append two new items
splice $test 2 1 'add this','and this one too'   # remove third item 'xyz' and insert two new items
splice $test 3 0 'add this','and this one too'   # insert two new items before fourth element '123' 
splice $test 4 2 'add this','and this one too'   # error 'splice : Index 4 out of range'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive implementation with no error handling, and probably a terrible performance profile...

```
function splice
{

    param
    (
        [string[]] $Array,
        [int32] $Index,
        [int32] $HowMany,
        [string[]] $Item
    )

    foreach( $x in ($Array | select-object -First $Index) )
    {
        write-output $x
    }

    foreach( $x in $Item )
    {
        write-output $x
    }
    
    foreach( $x in ($Array | select-object -Skip ($Index + $HowMany)) )
    {
        write-output $x
    }

}
```

Examples with test data taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```
$months = @( "Jan", "March", "April", "June" );
splice $months 1 0 "Feb";
# inserts at index 1
# expected output: Array ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "June"]

$months = @( "Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "June" );
splice $months 4 1 "May";
# replaces 1 element at index 4
# expected output: Array ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May"]
```

Note that it doesn't mutate the existing array in place though, but you can simulate that by assigning the result back to the variable - e.g.:

```
$months = @( "Jan", "March", "April", "June" );
$months = splice $months 1 0 "Feb";
```

There's probably some nicer things you can do with the `ValueFromPipeline` parameter attribute to allow you to pipe a variable in, but it's well past my bedtime here...